# Htaccess remove specific part of URL if contains another part

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to remove a specific part of a URL if it contains another specific part with .htaccess.

These requests: `https://example.com/nl/wc-api/mollie_return/*`

Need to become:

```
https://example.com/wc-api/mollie_return/*
```

So if it contains `/wc-api/mollie_return/`, the `/nl/` part before that needs to be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following rule in your /root/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^nl/(wc-api/mollie_return.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```